# Jquery Exclude a Selector?

Tags: jquery

I've got a form that I clear on focus. I've selected the whole form and it works great except that the submit button goes blank when I click it.

how can I exclude my input of input#submit from the following code?

```
    $(".wpcf7-form input, .wpcf7-form textarea").focus(function() {
 if( this.value == this.defaultValue ) {
  this.value = "";
  $(this).addClass('filled');
 }
}).blur(function() {
 if( !this.value.length ) {
  this.value = this.defaultValue;
  $(this).removeClass('filled');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the **[not](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)** selector to exclude what you want:

```
$(".wpcf7-form input:not('#submit_id'), .wpcf7-form textarea").focus(function() {
 // your code......
}
```

Or

```
$(".wpcf7-form input:not(input[type=submit]), .wpcf7-form textarea").focus(function() {
 // your code......
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude your input button (or buttons) from the set of inputs you already have.

```
$('input.are.blong.to.us') // give me a bunch of inputs
    .not('#submit')        // exclude input#submit
    .focus( ... )          
    .blur( ... );
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the [not-equal to](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) selector:

```
.wpcf7-form input[id!=submit]
```

or

```
.wpcf7-form input[type!=submit]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".wpcf7-form input:not(#submit), .wpcf7-form textarea")
```

[not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Comment: Even simpler: `$(".wpcf7-form :input:not(#submit)")` as `:input` includes `textarea`.

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen: That's not the same though, does he want `<select>` as well?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the css3-not selector.

A selector like that would be: `input:not([type=submit])`.

Example here: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MH68u/).

More info about the [`not`-selector here](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/).