# JQuery Button disabled on click after being enabled in reference to values in form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to JQuery: I am a little perplexed to ask but asking is better than the alternative:

I am trying to disable a button but enable it when something is in the field/textbox.
This is simply experimental, just getting my feet wet here.

Alternatively I could disable the button on `windows load` or apply the attribute directly on the form element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', true);

$('#myForm :input').blur(function(){
    if($('#myField').val() == '')
    {
        $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
});
```

The problem is after I enter a value and leave the field the button is enabled but as soon as I click the button it is disabled again:

What am I missing?

Thanks my friends.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the `button` is also considered an input field.

Try

```
$('#myForm :input:not(:button)').
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VXPQ7/)

Also use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to set disabled state

Comment: Thanks this is great to know! This gave me such a pain. :)

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
$('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // to disable buttons
$('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled'); // to enable them
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, this should work

HTML sample

```
<input type = "text" id = "txt1">
<button class = "btnSubmit">Submit</button>
```

And the jquery

```
$(".btnSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#txt1").keyup(function() {
    if(jQuery.trim($(this).val()) != '') {
       $('.btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! Unfortunately this does not work on 'type=Submit`. I have tried everything and all variation including everything on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001322/jquery-exclude-a-selector; but no luck, unless I changed the type to button.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myForm:input').on('keyup' , function() {

    if($.trim($('#myField').val()).length > 0){
       $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
       $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
    }

});
```

****This would work. Please try****

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,`onkeyup` check if the textbox is empty is so disbale the button , else enable the button.

**HTML:**

```
 <form id="myForm">
       <input id="myField" type="text"/>
       <input id="btnSubmit" value="hi" type="button"/>

  </form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //Load with button disabled,since the value of the textbox will be empty initially
        $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
        //onkeyup check if the textbox is empty or not
        $('#myForm input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
           if($('#myField').val() == '')
             {
               $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
             }
            else
            {
               $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
            }
           });
          });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#myForm input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
       if($('#myField').val() == '')
         {             
           $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);         
         }
        else
        {
           $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
        }
       }); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
         <input id="myField" type="text"/>
         <input id="btnSubmit" value="hi" type="button"/>

      </form>
```